# AutoIT Window Info Tool not working properly with dialog boxes of Windows

Tags: selenium, automation, autoit

I am currently automating the firefox browser using Autoit to perform some download. To download i need to know the control elements of the Dialog box that opens up when i click on download button.I tried using the Autoit Window Info Tool to gather the information the windows dialog box for download, but the Autoit Window info tool is just showing the name of the dialog box and no other control elements are shown.Is there any other tool which can capture such info.I am trying really hard on it, but no results still.

Comment: I don't think so. But I may be wrong... Did you consider another options on how to download the file? [Could you just download it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java) [using your language?](http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/) [Or maybe even a tool done for Selenium to do the job?](https://github.com/Ardesco/Ebselen/blob/master/ebselen-core/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/ebselen/customhandlers/FileDownloader.java) [Or install this and just click the file?](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/download-statusbar/)

Comment: Yes I downloaded it using the Autoit Recorder by recording the whole process and then modifying the script and re-running it in the Autoit Editor ,it worked well. But I want to ask Why I was not able to retrieve the information related to the Download Dialog Box using the Autoit info toolbar. Is there  any other similar tool for this which can perform the same function of retrieving the information of the download dialog box.

Comment: Can you provide your code you tried with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the version of AutoIT that you used? I was encountered the same situation that Autoit Window Info can not recognize the control info in an window. Finally I found because I install the AutoIt of version 3.3.6.1. If I use the window Info tool of version 3.3.0.0, It can recognize the control info that the version of 3.3.6.1 can not recognize. You can try with the Window Info Tool of version 3.3.0.0